# "would like to ask" or "would like to invite"?

Tags: etymology, expressions, phrase-requests

When trying to ask someone to write me a recommendation letter politely, shall I use

> I would like to ask you to...

or

> I would like to invite you to ...

?

Comment: I would appreciate your writing me a recommendation.

Comment: To me, the only real difference is that "invite" sounds more formal.

Comment: This Q. is primarily opinion-based & therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand it is when you ask someone, you are requesting something, but when you invite them, you are requesting their participation.  You invite them to dinner, to a party, to tea.  You ask them to pass the salt, or ask them a question, expecting something in return. Perhaps consider starting the sentence with "May I ask you kindly to...... or "May I ask you respectfully to.....